# Rename file 20181207_ProdAndPressuresExport.csv to ProdAndPressuresExport.csv

Tags: c#

I have the following C# code but having issues renaming the file to what I want (ProdAndPressuresExport.csv).  It is renaming the file as ProdAndPressuresExportProdAndPressuresExport.csv and also moving the rename file up 1 folder.  I would like for it to stay in its original file path C:\TEMP\CSVFile\ProdAndPressuresExport.  Please help.

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string DIRECTORY_PATH = @"C:\TEMP\CSVFile\ProdAndPressuresExport";

            const string FILE_NAME_TEMPLATE = "*_ProdAndPressuresExport.CSV";

            if (Directory.Exists(DIRECTORY_PATH))
            {
                string[] filePathList = Directory.GetFiles(DIRECTORY_PATH, FILE_NAME_TEMPLATE);

                foreach (string filePath in filePathList)
                {
                    if (File.Exists(filePath))
                    {
                        string newName = DIRECTORY_PATH + filePath.Split('_')[1];
                        File.Move(filePath, newName);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always use `Path.Combine` to construct paths, rather than string concatenation.

```
string newName = DIRECTORY_PATH + filePath.Split('_')[1];
```

Should be

```
string newName = Path.Combine(DIRECTORY_PATH, filePath.Split('_')[1]);
```

Otherwise you miss the directory separator character, and your file will end up in the parent folder *above your intended folder* with an unintentionally concatenated name.